# Manipulate Raio value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML:

```
<li class='gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible gsurvey-survey-field' id='field_1_213'>
    <label class='gfield_label'>MOOD</label>
    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_likert'>
        <table class='gsurvey-likert' id='input_1_213'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class='gsurvey-likert-row-label' scope='col'></th>
                    <th class='gsurvey-likert-choice-label' scope='col'>RECOMMEND</th>
                    <th class='gsurvey-likert-choice-label' scope='col'>NOT RECOMMEND</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-row-label' data-label=''>APPETITE</td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_1_1' name='input_213.1' type='radio' value='glikertrowc23a480e:glikertcol213e396906a'></td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='NOT RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_1_2' name='input_213.1' type='radio' value='glikertrowc23a480e:glikertcol213ef7a9a10'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-row-label' data-label=''>SOCIAL</td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_2_1' name='input_213.2' type='radio' value='glikertrow2129f677:glikertcol213e396906a'></td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='NOT RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_2_2' name='input_213.2' type='radio' value='glikertrow2129f677:glikertcol213ef7a9a10'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-row-label' data-label=''>PASSION</td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_3_1' name='input_213.3' type='radio' value='glikertrow947f470d:glikertcol213e396906a'></td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='NOT RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_3_2' name='input_213.3' type='radio' value='glikertrow947f470d:glikertcol213ef7a9a10'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-row-label' data-label=''>RELIEF</td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_4_1' name='input_213.4' type='radio' value='glikertrow6ac41353:glikertcol213e396906a'></td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='NOT RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_4_2' name='input_213.4' type='radio' value='glikertrow6ac41353:glikertcol213ef7a9a10'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-row-label' data-label=''>FLO</td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_5_1' name='input_213.5' type='radio' value='glikertrow7b8e0a41:glikertcol213e396906a'></td>
                    <td class='gsurvey-likert-choice' data-label='NOT RECOMMEND'><input id='choice_1_213_5_2' name='input_213.5' type='radio' value='glikertrow7b8e0a41:glikertcol213ef7a9a10'></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to manupulate the value of the input to be default or none/empty and update the parent class.
Someone should be able to check an option from a row  and they should be able to uncheck all choices (2 choice in a row) if they change their mind and don't want to choose anything. Clicking on an input currently selects an option, I want an option to deselect the selection on clicking again. TO comply with the existing jQuery, I tested the form and see if I change the value of an input to empty, it gets deselected and changing to the default value, it gets selected.

The current code allows selection to any one of the 2 choices, but they can not be deselected.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var click = $('.gsurvey-likert-choice');
        var input = click.find('input:radio');
        var inputVal = input.val();
        input.attr('data-default', inputVal);
        input.attr('data-alt');

        click.on("click", function() {
        var input = $(this).find('input:radio');    
        var def = input.attr('data-default');
        var alt = input.attr('data-alt');
        (input.val() == def) ? input.val(alt) : input.val(def);
        $(this).toggleClass('none-selected');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, show us some code.

Comment: Code updated to show my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my understanding you do not need to use classes. Anyway, one solution is with the JS `setTimeout` function.

```
        $("input[type='radio']").mouseup(
            function (e) {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    var item = $(this);
                    setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            item.prop('checked', false);
                        },
                        200
                    );
                }
            }
        );
```

More info about the `setTimeout` function here: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: That does not solve the issue, please check the form link.

Comment: What should i see on the form link? `I want an option to deselect the selection on clicking again.` > https://jsfiddle.net/13xwLnka/